# Grub fails on 2015 MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 20.04 and no MacOS

Tags: boot, grub2, macbook-pro, moklistrt

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 20.04 which won't boot - I get a message on screen saying "Failed to set MoklistRT: Invalid Parameter ...", and the system fails to load. This started after an update and I believe it is due to Bug #1867092.
My problem is that the MBP SSD has only Ubuntu 20.04 on it - MacOS is not installed.
I'm unable to get a Ubuntu liveCD to boot.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by removing the original Apple PCIe AHCI SSD and replaced it with a new MBR formatted NVMe SSD. The MBP then booted from a USB distro, and I installed on the new SSD. My MBP is an A1502 early 2015 retina, which was running Catalina - this meant the firmware would support NVMe. Performance with NVMe is higher than AHCI.